# How to change $rootScope value in an ng-click function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to change the value of `$rootScope.name` that I set in the controller by another function in another controller, but when I access the `$rootScope.name` in another controller the value remains the same as it was set. For example:

```
app.controller('homectrl', function($scope, $rootScope){

$rootScope.name = "joshua";

})

app.controller('aboutctrl', function($scope, $rootScope){

$scope.send = function(newname)
{
$rootScope.name = newname;
}

})

app.controller('servicectrl', function($scope, $rootScope){

console.log($rootScope.name); // this outputs joshua instead of new name set in send function in about controller

})
```

Comment: You need to inject the controller.

Comment: Don't use $rootScope, it's a bad practice. Create a specialized service to share the value between controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can not push the button which triggers the `send()` method fast enough to make the `servicectrl` output the new name. if you really want to see what is in `$rootScope.name` after you pushed the button you should observe the value or $watch it, eg. by changing the `servicectrl` like this:

```
$rootScope.$watch('name', function(newname) {
    console.log($rootScope.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In a case like that I would avoid using `$rootScope`, but instead I would use a *factory service*, shared between the two controllers.

Here is a working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('homectrl', function($scope, NameService){

  $scope.name = NameService.name;
  
  $scope.$watch(function(){return NameService.name}, function(newValue, oldValue){
    $scope.name = newValue;
});
  
});

app.controller('aboutctrl', function($scope, NameService){

  $scope.name = NameService.name;
  
  $scope.send = function(newname){
    NameService.changeName($scope.name);
    console.log('New name!', $scope.name);
  }

});

app.factory('NameService', function(){

  return {
    name : 'joshua',
    changeName : function(newName){
      this.name = newName;
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="homectrl">
    <h3>Home Controller </h3>
    <p>{{name}}</p>
  </div>
  
  <hr>
  
  <div ng-controller="aboutctrl">
    <h3>About Controller </h3>
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
    <button ng-click="send($scope.name)">Change</button>
  </div>


</div>
```